# Centering Equations and Having Space between variables

Tags: equations, align

I have two questions:

1. I have a list of equations that I wish to center, I am using align but it's not working.
2. I wish to obtain a fair space when I am writing two variables (like 2MU looks so stick together)

Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    &\diff{J}{U} = 0 \\
    &MU + M^TU + 2r = 0 \\
    &2MU+2r = 0 \\
    &U = M^{-1}r \\
    &U = (H^TQH+R)^{-1}(\tilde{F}^TQ\tilde{F}-2\tilde{F}^TQW+W^TQW)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You want `gather` rather than `align` (with no `&`). And you don't want to space the letters, trust me.

Comment: you have the `&` in the wrong place, the intended place is `&=`

Answer (score 1):

If you want centered the equations you, as said correctly `@David Carlisle`, should to put the `&` in the corrected place. After in your MWE there is not the diffcoeff package for to use the command `\diff`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \diff{J}{U} & = 0 \\
    MU + M^TU + 2r & = 0 \\
    2MU+2r & = 0 \\
    U &= M^{-1}r \\
    U &= (H^TQH+R)^{-1}(\tilde{F}^TQ\tilde{F}-2\tilde{F}^TQW+W^TQW)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]